# Combine two event tables into a single timeline

Tags: postgresql, join, window-functions

Given two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (ts timestamp, foo text);
CREATE TABLE bar (ts timestamp, bar text);
```

I wish to write a query that returns values for `ts`, `foo`, and `bar` that represents a unified view of the most recent values. In other words, if `foo` contained:

```
ts | foo
--------
1  | A
7  | B
```

and `bar` contained:

```
ts | bar
--------
3  | C
5  | D
9  | E
```

I want a query that returns:

```
ts | foo | bar
--------------
1  | A   | null
3  | A   | C
5  | A   | D
7  | B   | D
9  | B   | E
```

If both tables have an event at the same time, the order does not matter.

I have been able to create the structure needed using union all and dummy values:

```
SELECT ts, foo, null as bar FROM foo
UNION ALL SELECT ts, null as foo, bar FROM bar
```

which will give me a linear timeline of new values, but I'm not quite able to work out how to populate the null values based on the previous rows. I've tried the `lag` window function, but AFAICT it will only look at the previous row, not recursively backward. I've looked at recursive CTEs, but I'm not quite sure how to set up the start and termination conditions.

Comment: Are values in `foo` and `bar` strictly ascending over time or is the test case misleading in this respect?

Comment: To save anyone else the hassle, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/511414

Comment: Rather than changing the nature of the question after an answer has been given, please ask a *new question*. You can always link to this one for reference. (You can even provide your own answer if you have one.) The original version should be interesting to the general public. Let's not pack to much in a single question.

Comment: Sorry for the overload. I've removed the follow up and added it [as a new question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106514).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a **`FULL [OUTER] JOIN`**, combined with two rounds of **window functions**:

```
SELECT ts
     , min(foo) OVER (PARTITION BY foo_grp) AS foo
     , min(bar) OVER (PARTITION BY bar_grp) AS bar
FROM (
   SELECT ts, f.foo, b.bar
        , count(f.foo) OVER (ORDER BY ts) AS foo_grp
        , count(b.bar) OVER (ORDER BY ts) AS bar_grp
   FROM   foo f
   FULL   JOIN bar b USING (ts)
   ) sub;
```

Since `count()` does not count NULL values it conveniently only increases with every non-null value, thereby forming groups that will share the same value. In the outer `SELECT`, `min()` (or `max()`) likewise ignores NULL values, thereby picking the one non-null value per group. Voilá.

Related `FULL JOIN` case:

- [Add up conditional counts on multiple columns of the same table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30984130/939860)

It's one of those cases where a procedural solution might just be faster, since it can get the job done in a single scan. Like this **plpgsql function**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_merge_foobar()
  RETURNS TABLE(ts int, foo text, bar text)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
#variable_conflict use_column
DECLARE
   last_foo text;
   last_bar text;
BEGIN
   FOR ts, foo, bar IN
      SELECT ts, f.foo, b.bar
      FROM   foo f
      FULL   JOIN bar b USING (ts)
      ORDER  BY 1
   LOOP
      IF foo IS NULL THEN foo := last_foo;
      ELSE                last_foo := foo;
      END IF;

      IF bar IS NULL THEN bar := last_bar;
      ELSE                last_bar := bar;
      END IF;

      RETURN NEXT;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM f_merge_foobar();
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1cbb193db0f3662c4192ec82b0f5e609)*, demonstrating both.
 <sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/4e95c/1).</sub>

Related answer explaining the `#variable_conflict use_column`:

- [Naming conflict between function parameter and result of JOIN with USING clause](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/105831/naming-conflict-between-function-parameter-and-result-of-join-with-using-clause/105902#105902)

Comment: Interesting problem isn't it. I think an efficient solution probably requires creation of a `coalesce`-like window function.

Comment: @CraigRinger: Indeed. I find myself wishing, wondering, thinking .. that this somehow should be possible without subquery, but I failed to find a way. It's one of those cases where a plpgsql function will be faster since it can scan each table once.

Comment: @Christopher: I would be interested in the performance of each variant in your setup. `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`, best of 5 ...?

Comment: Pity that Postgres has not implemented yet `IGNORE NULLS` (as Oracle has: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fab35/1 ).

Comment: @ypercube: That would be easy for Oracle since it's not implementing NULL properly to begin with. ;)  BTW, the Oracle variant gets simpler with `USING`, too: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fab35/5

Comment: I don't know what you mean with "not properly". I guess the `NULL` vs. empty string?

Comment: @ypercube: Yes, Oracle simple does not store NULL values at all and consequently can't tell the difference between `''` and NULL.