# Function for matching email address returns full table of emails

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, functions

I am using Postgres 9.4.6.

I have created a Function for finding email address that match an email variable that is passed. However, when I search for 'user@email.com' I get a full table of email addresses that do not match 'user@email.com'. My function is as follows:-

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION spgetmatchingusers(IN email text)
RETURNS TABLE(email character, password character, userid smallint, teamname character, reset_password character, reset_password_expiry timestamp with time zone) AS
$BODY$
select "email", "password", "userid", "teamname", "reset_password", "reset_password_expiry"
from "RegisteredUsers"
where LOWER("RegisteredUsers"."email") = LOWER(email)
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE
COST 100
ROWS 1000;
ALTER FUNCTION spgetmatchingusers(text)
OWNER TO bjlizgykrnyffr;
```

I call the function with:

```
select * from spgetmatchingusers('user@email.com')
```

If I type:

```
select * from spgetmatchingusers('randomtext')
```

I still get a full table of users returned.

For reference, my RegisteredUsers table is as follows...

```
CREATE TABLE "RegisteredUsers"
(
userid smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('user_id_seq'::regclass),
teamname character(50) NOT NULL,
first_name character(50),
surname character(50),
email character(50),
company_name character(50),
password character(50),
reset_password character(50),
reset_password_expiry timestamp with time zone,
CONSTRAINT "RegisteredUsers_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (userid)
)
WITH (
OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE "RegisteredUsers"
OWNER TO bjlizgykrnyffr;
```

Apologies if I have missed something obvious but after searching around the internet I can't seem to work out where I have gone wrong!

Comment: Use different name for the parameter than the column name.

Comment: That did the trick. The moral of the story...make sure my parameter names are different to my column names

Comment: See also this related question: [Naming conflict between function parameter and result of JOIN with USING clause](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/105831/naming-conflict-between-function-parameter-and-result-of-join-with-using-clause/105902#105902)