# 42702 'column reference "id" is ambiguous' for RETURNING of table-returning PL/pgSQL function

Tags: postgresql, functions, errors, postgresql-10, plpgsql

This works:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sql_fun()
RETURNS TABLE (id UUID) AS $$
  INSERT INTO foo DEFAULT VALUES
  RETURNING id
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;

SELECT *
FROM sql_fun();
```

This doesn't:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION plpgsql_fun()
RETURNS TABLE (id UUID) AS $$
  BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    INSERT INTO foo DEFAULT VALUES
    RETURNING id;
  END
$$ LANGUAGE PLpgSQL;

SELECT *
FROM plpgsql_fun();
```

Is this a bug in PL/pgSQL? How can I fix this while keeping the return type as is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to qualify all columns from `RETURNING` which have the same name as the columns from `RETURNS TABLE` with the name of the table which was `INSERTED INTO`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION plpgsql_fun()
RETURNS TABLE (id UUID) AS $$
  BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    INSERT INTO foo DEFAULT VALUES
    RETURNING foo.id;
  END
$$ LANGUAGE PLpgSQL;
```

If the name of the table is long and there are multiple columns, the name can be aliased:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION plpgsql_fun()
RETURNS TABLE (id UUID, foo INT, bar INT) AS $$
  BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    INSERT INTO table_with_a_very_long_name AS x DEFAULT VALUES
    RETURNING x.id, x.foo, x.bar;
  END
$$ LANGUAGE PLpgSQL;
```

Comment: Don't forget to mark your own answer as correct - it might help others find a resolution to similar problems in the future!

Answer (score 2):

> How can I fix this while keeping the return type as is?

You can even fix it keeping the whole function as is, by adding the [special configuration parameter `#variable_conflict`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-implementation.html):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION plpgsql_fun()
  RETURNS TABLE (id uuid)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS  -- see below
$func$
#variable_conflict use_column  -- !! 
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY
   INSERT INTO foo AS f DEFAULT VALUES
   RETURNING f.id;
END
$func$;
```

But it's good form to table-qualify columns names anyway, like you found yourself - if at all possible. There are corner cases, where it's not easily possible:

- [Naming conflict between function parameter and result of JOIN with USING clause](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/105831/naming-conflict-between-function-parameter-and-result-of-join-with-using-clause)

Related:

- [INSERT INTO … RETURNING - ambiguous column reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39283973/939860)
- [How to return result of a SELECT inside a function in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7945958/939860)

In early versions, Postgres did not raise an exception, but silently preferred parameter values over columns:

- [Postgres function NULL value for row that references NEW](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12172475/939860)

And avoid CaMeL-casing the language name `plpgsql`. That stops working when quoted, which (unfortunately) is a wide-spread malpractice.

Comment: The documentation uses `SQL` and `C` vs. `plpgsql`, `pltcl`, `plperl` and `plpythonu`. Interesting.  I generally don't use quotes if not needed, though.